# How to get google plus follower's name and unique id

Tags: php, google-api

I have created the Google application from which i got app_key, app_secret..etc.
I am able to get the logged-in user's information. How to find the Google-plus follower's list? Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-developers/dBslr8--Y3g) it has not been implemented.

But this [other page](http://www.emoticode.net/ruby/get-google-page-followers-count-with-google-api.html) is using REST.